# How to detect memory leak <Allocated Prior To Attach>?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode9.3

I am trying to detect what's the object that casues a memory issue by using the instruments, however is seems that there is an issue in Xcode 9.3 with using the instruments as mentioned at: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97592, also this one could be related:

[Observing property crashes Instruments (Leaks profile) Xcode 9.3 (Swift 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729233/observing-property-crashes-instruments-leaks-profile-xcode-9-3-swift-4-1)

So far, here is the allocations list:

[image]

As shown, the responsible caller for all records is `"<Allocated Prior To Attach>"`

And here is the call trees:

[image]

which seems to be an odd behavior for the first record (the issue).

**My problem is**:

if the instruments work as expected, I could directly figure it out by knowing what's the object that causes the issue (the object is not getting deallocated instead of  `<Allocated Prior To Attach>`). At this point, is there any way to know what's the object that causes the issue?

Comment: I'm on the same road..fixing leaks but not luck...

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Makaille not yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Turning off "`Record reference counts`" in "`File`">"`Recording options`" as a workaround.